# module 'Tensorflow' has no atributte

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm getting these weird errors in Google Colab when using TensorFlow, like:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute
> 'reset_default_graph'

or

> module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

Help would appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to downgrade your tensorflow version. Try running this in the first cell before importing tensorflow: `!pip install tensorflow==1.15`

Comment: Do you have a local file in your project that is named `tensorflow.py`?

Comment: @Anwarvic That solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @StanislavJirák, Glad I could help :)

Comment: @StanislavJirák, I've added the answer which might help other people

Answer (score 2):

This problem happens because the current version installed on GoogleColab is `tensorflow 2.2.0`. And apparently, the code you're using assumes that `tensorflow 1.x` is installed.

So, you can fix this issue using two ways:

- Either downgrading your `tensorflow` to `1.x` like so:

  ```
   !pip install tensorflow==1.15
  ```
- Or you can use the methods provided in `tensorflow.comat.v1` package like `tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph` instead of `tf.reset_default_graph` and `tf.compat.v1.placeholder` instead of `tf.placeholder`.

I really encourage the first solution as the second solution will require a lot of changes that can lead to mistakes.

I really  used in

Answer (score 1):

Try using `tf.compat.v1.placeholder` and `tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph`. If you have any more attribute errors, you can look at the tensorflow documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve version issues in TensorFlow, it's a good idea to use this below technique to import v1 (version 1 or TensorFlow 1. x) and we also can disable the TensorFlow 2. x behaviors.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Here you don't have to uninstall or re-install anything.